# How to have same Chrome extension id in open source project

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I was let Chrome Web Store dashboard create private key therefore when I use "Load unpacked extension" in Extensions tab, id of it becomes random. As solution I added "key" field to manifest.json file and used public key from dashboard. This gives proper id but then I can't commit this manifest.json file because even that public key easy to find still won't be allowed to share in public I think. I checked many open source projects which using native messaging and none of them includes key field in their manifest file.

Then I tried packing extension myself so I can have private key file but then when I use "Load unpacked extension" I can't use this private key file like including "key.pem" in same directory and then ignoring this "key.pem" file in git. And doing "Pack extension" and dragging this crx file every single time when I need to test something would be inefficient.

Reason why I need same id is because I'm using native messaging and it have "allowed_origins" field which require same id otherwise not works. So what is best way to have same id and still avoid committing this with git?

Comment: "even that public key easy to find still won't be allowed to share in public I think." - Why do you think that?